# TTStyleSheet not working when restored by TTNavigator

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, ttnavigator

I'm using version 1.1 of the Three20 library and I'm setting a global style sheet to change the `navigationBarTintColor` in my app delegate like this:

```
[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:
  [[[DefaultStyleSheet alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

That is working just fine, except when my app state is restored by calling `restoreViewControllers` in `TTNavigator`. In that case, the navigation bar is showing the iOS default, pale blue color. When I navigate on to the next view, the style sheet takes effect again.

I also posted this question on the Three20 Google Group. I'll update here if I find an answer there, of course.

Comment: I thought there used to be a way to answer your own questions, but I can't find it right now. Probably missing something obvious... In the mean time, if someone is looking for a solution to this, you'll find the answer here: http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/affbd2a0ee2851c8

Comment: Never mind, I just found the button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time, I found a solution to this with the help of the kind people on the [Three20 Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/affbd2a0ee2851c8).

In short: The global style sheet will work correctly, if all view controllers descend from TTViewController. When inheriting directly from UIViewController, a work-around is needed to
enforce the wanted behavior. Use either categories or a common super-class to implement the following method for your view controllers:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Work-around for Three20 style sheet misbehavior. See:
    //  http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/affbd2a0ee2851c8
    //  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406827/ttstylesheet-not-workin-when-restored-by-ttnavigator
    if (self.navigationController) {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = TTSTYLEVAR(navigationBarTintColor);
    }
}
```